# How to include "Not now" button in AccountManager addAccount page

Tags: android

Given in project we're developing a custom provisioning App, which will be started during the first Android boot. It should include a page to create a Google Account (just like in the standard Android system).

The Account manager is called using a Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT);
intent.putExtra("firstRun", true);
intent.putExtra("account_types", new String[]{ "com.google" });
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_GOOGLE_ACCOUNT);
```

How can I include a "Not now" / "Skip" button in the resulting UI? Right now it only offers the choice of "Existing" or "Create Account".

**EDIT: Screen shot from a standard OOBE experience**

[image: Standard OOBE experience with "Not now" button]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no API/method that would allow to customize the buttons of this UI.

You should not prompt a user with this page if he doesn't want to connect and I would suggest you to adapt you UI with a register with Google (that would fire this intent) // skip in your own UI

When you launch the startActivityForResult, you suppose that the user wants to login with Google

Comment: I was afraid to get an answer like that. When activating a standard Android tablet, the UI contains a "Not Now" flow though - and I was hoping to be able to tap into it.

Comment: I was looking for this screen while replying and couldn't fint it.. As you can see, as explained in my answer, the buttons are in the app UI, not in the started Activity. If I am not wrong, this Activity belong to the Google part and is not from the Open Source bits of Android, so the best you could do is to mimic this screen

Comment: Yes - and I see your point. Will go with a solution like this. Thank you for the suggestion.